# Is there a program to shorten this?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm new to python, started doing it in quarantine just for fun. I was working on some Python code the other day, and decided to create an image with the turtle program. I'm seeing a lot of repetition here, so I was wondering if there was a way I could shorten it. Here's the code:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
House = turtle.Turtle()

House.forward(150)
House.left(90)
House.forward(110)
House.left(45)
House.forward(110)
House.left(90)
House.forward(110)
House.left(45)
House.forward(110)

wn.mainloop()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For this explicit example, you can try this:

```
House.forward(150)
for iter in range(2):
    for left_pos in [90,45]:
        House.left(left_pos)
        House.forward(110)
wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
left_vals = [90, 45, 90, 45]
House.forward(150)
for v in left_vals:
  House.left(v)
  House.forward(110)
```

You can always use a for loop to reduce code repetition. If there is a pattern, you can use a function instead of putting values in the list. Here for example it seems like you call 90 and 45 in order. So you can do this:

```
House.forward(150)
for i in range(4):
  House.left(45 * (2 - i%2))
  House.forward(110)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import turtle


wn = turtle.Screen()
house = turtle.Turtle()

# function table for the turtle (fill up with other functions)
draw = {
    'F': house.forward,
    'L': house.left,
}

# direction, value
instructions = (
    ('F', 150),
    ('L', 90),
    ('F', 110),
    ('L', 45),
    ('F', 110),
    ('L', 90),
    ('F', 110),
    ('L', 45),
    ('F', 110),
)

for dir, val in instructions:
    draw[dir](val)  # call each function from the dict with the value

wn.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's correct the initial `forward()` distance to match the roof size.  Then the program breaks down to four repetitions of the same `left()` and `forward()` motion with an alternating angle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.forward(110 * 2 ** 0.5)

angle = 90

for _ in range(4):
    turtle.left(angle)
    turtle.forward(110)

    angle = 135 - angle

screen = Screen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Here's something:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
House = turtle.Turtle()

for n in [(150,90),(110,45),(110,90),(110,45)]:
    House.forward(n[0])
    House.left(n[1])
House.forward(110)

wn.mainloop()
```